# Build Process for a Visual C++ 2008 Express Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I have a VS 2008 C++ project, with one very small and simple code file.  I need to write an app to generate this file and build the project into a Win32 DLL.  I will need to deliver a free compiler etc. with the app to my client, so I can't automate VS to do this.

How would I best go about this?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before.

Comment: @dirkgently, I figured one might have, but I hit a bit of a mental block formulating search terms.  I thought something might come up in the 'auto-search' that appears when I posted the question, but nothing looked suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2008 Express installs the command line compiler (in fact the installer has an option so you only get the command line stuff). So getting a free compiler is no problem.

If you really only need to build a single file into a DLL, a cl command using the '/LD' option should be enough to do the trick (though you'll likely need at least a couple other options).

If you want to get fancy, I'm not sure if The Express SKU includes nmake.exe (but I imagine it does).

Comment: I'll also need to link, and I no nothing about that either.

Comment: cl.exe will take care of linking, too. You'll need to read the docs on cl.exe to determine which options you need.  If you have a working VS project, the project's properties dialog has panels that will show you the options it's using to build the project.